# php simplehtmldom array too big

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I am scraping a web page with simplehtmldom. Everything works fine on smaller tables. However, one of the tables I am scraping has over 9000 entries. This large number gives me the  following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on boolean in domtest.php on line 4`

The code I am using is from a similar thread (cannot remember from which one, so if this code is yours please let me know so I can give you credit).

```
<?php
// LEGAL: This code is not mine, I found it on https:stackoverflow.com
require('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('node_list.html');
$table = $html->find('table', 1);
$rowData = array();
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row)
{
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $flight = array();

    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell)
        {
            // push the cell's text to the array
            $flight[] = $cell->plaintext;
        }

    $rowData[] = $flight;
}
print_r ( $rowData ) ;
?>
```

I run this script from the command line. I tried increasing the memory size in php.ini and on the command line with `-d memory_limit=128M`. If I split the file into smaller chunks then I do not get the error and it works absolutely fantastic, but as one file I get the error as above. The name of my script is "domtest.php".

Any ideas?

Thank you

Danny

Comment: This is a common issue. Consider switching to a different library.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Any suggestions as to which library?

Comment: I use [this one](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom)

Comment: Thank you ... I have switched over to the one you recommended ...

Comment: Thank you ... advanced_html_dom works 100% ... appreciate your help